# string.lower in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I had a working python script, but something must have changed in python 3.

For example if I wanted to convert argument 1 to lowercase:

```
import string
print(string.lower(sys.argv[1]))
```

It says that `'module' object has no attribute 'lower'` - OK, I understand, `string` is a module now.

If I remove the import, and write only `string.lower('FOO')`, it complains that `name 'string' is not defined`.

So what's the correct way to do convert a string to lowercase?

Comment: Yes, there is no `string` variable in your second example. So what do you want to convert?

Comment: Why not `sys.argv[1].lower()`?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I didn't notice that the documentation I found from google search was for version 2.7

Answer (score 17):

You can use `sys.argv[1].lower()`

```
>>> "FOo".lower()
'foo'
```

`lower()` is a method of string objects itself.

`string` module has been changed in Python 3, it no longer contains the methods related to `str` objects, it now only contains the constants mentioned below.

You can also use `str.lower("Mystring")` but that's unnecessary here as you can simply use `"Mystring".lower()`.

```
>>> import string  # Python 3
>>> dir(string)
['ChainMap', 'Formatter', 'Template', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '_re', '_string', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace']
```

Comment: or `str.lower(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: @Elazar While that works and is instructive in how methods work, it's an awful way to write that.

Comment: @delnan I agree - it's just more similar to the original code in question.

Answer (score 5):

It's `str` not `string`:

```
>>> str.lower("HELLO")
'hello'
```

Hence the reason you get the `name 'string' is not defined.` error is that there currently exists no variable in scope called `string`.

Comment: This works as a consequence of how methods work, but it's not to one obvious way to call a method (that would be `"HELLO".lower()`).

Comment: @delnan I agree, but it's closest to the OP's original code, and directly answers his question of why `string.lower` wasn't working.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, because `str.lower("HELLO")` works in both Python 2.x **and** Python 3.x, and the question is why `string.lower("HELLO")` does not work in 3.x.

Comment: @DietrichEpp `string.lower()` works in ***neither*** python 2.x or 3.x

Comment: You are mistaken.  `string.lower("HELLO")` works in Python 2.x.  I just tried it.  The person asking the question tried it.  Did you remember to `import string`?

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it. My bad

Answer (score 3):

The object oriented correct way is:

```
'FOO'.lower()
```

In your example:

```
print(sys.argv[1].lower())
```

Comment: The question is whether the *object-oriented way* is always the correct one ;)

Answer (score 3):

To add, while some people prefer the object-oriented way (calling the method of the str object), some may still prefer the older way -- with functions or operators. It depends also on the problem being solved. (If you do not agree, think for example about `(1.5).__add__(3)`.)

You can easily create your own (simpler) name for the function that you need to make it more readable. You only should think about whether it will be readable (in future for you and now) for everyone:

```
>>> lower = str.lower
>>> lower('SoMe CaPiTaL LetTerS to Be LoWeRED')
'some capital letters to be lowered'
```